# Windows essentials CALs unusable?

Tags: rdp, windows-server-2016, cal

I just installed a new Windows Server 2016 Essentials hoping to create a test environment for RemoteApp hosting. So far good, all worked great, until I started getting a "Remote Desktop licensing mode is not configured" warning message.

Running the RD Licensing diagnoser says "Number of licenses available for clients : 0"...

Well, then I started searching the web for CALs, but [Microsoft's documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/windows-server-pricing) is crystal clear: Essentials version contains 25 CALs and cannot be extended. Perfect in my case - but where the heck are these CALs, how can I make them available?

Answer (score 1):

25 CALs of server = max. 25 computers connect your server **at same time**. 
You can also see computers connected to the server from the active directory